# Looking for probability of the product of a and b

Tags: probability, optimization

The question states: $$
a,b \in [0,1] 
$$
$$
P(a\cdot b > \frac{1}{2}) = ? 
$$
I am assuming that the probability $P$ is at most $1-\sqrt{0.5}$ since, $\sqrt{0.5}^2 = 0.5$, meaning that if and $a$ and $b$ are less than $\sqrt{0.5}$ then the product $a \cdot b < 0.5$

But that's as far as I can go, I am not sure how to figure out the answer.

I tried to do $(a+b) > 2\sqrt{0.5}$ , but I am not sure what the upperbound should be and how to derive the probability from there.

Comment: What is the distribution of a and b?

Comment: Have you tried graphing the region?

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed, uniform distribution? just any number from 0 to 1 all with equal probability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $a,b\sim \text{Unif}([0,1])$ iid , then we are looking for the region

$$\begin{align}
P(a>\frac{1}{2b})\\=\int_{[0,1]^2} \mathbf{1}_{\{a>\frac{1}{2b}\}}dA\\=1-\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}1dx -\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{1}{2x}dx\\ = \frac{1}{2} - \ln(1)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{1}{2})\\
=\frac{1}{2}(1+\ln(\frac{1}{2}))\\
\approx0.15.
\end{align}$$

Please observe the following python code snippet as proof by law of large numbers, which does not agree with @wbitting95's answer of 0.100856.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random

# Prints approximately 0.15
sum([random.rand()*random.rand()>1/2 for _ in range(1000000)])/1000000
```

[image]

Comment: But a, and b aren't picked independently, thus it's not iid. Once one is picked, it influences how small the other is allowed to be.

Comment: @wbitting95 where is this stated in the question? It just says that a,b are chosen from the unit interval, and then we look at the event involving their product

Comment: We are assuming/looking for $ab>1/2$, thus once we determine the value of $a$, we require $b>\frac{1}{2a}$ .

Comment: It's not explicit, but implicit it is required to get a product of 0.5.

Comment: The a and b are pulled iid, and we are asking what the probability is that their product is greater than 0.5. $\{ab>1/2\}$ and  $\{b>\frac{1}{2a}\}$ are the same event. There is no dependence required between the random variables a and b in order to get a product greater than 0.5, this product will be greater than 0.5 15% of the time by the calculation

Comment: @ConquestAce could you please clarify if a and b are sampled iid on [0,1]?

Comment: @wbitting95, what would the question would be if a and b are not picked independently? It seems that the question states that a,b are iid $Unif[0,1]$, and we are looking for the probability that $ab > \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: The varaibles are both iid

Comment: @ConquestAce Do you agree with my proof? I even added some python code to empircally convince you of my answer using the law of large numbers :)

Comment: Although  I don't follow the logic too well and 10% seemed a bit to low from @wbitting95 's answer, I can't cant argue against law of large numbers lol.

Do you mind explaining  the third line in your solution @random_0620?

Comment: Yeah, I definitely had/have a mistake somewhere. I'll keep an eye open

Comment: @ConquestAce I added an image to make the intuition easier!

Comment: @ConquestAce If you found this helpful I would love if you marked it correct! :D

Comment: I found my dumb error!

There should not be a xy in my integral. Since the distribution is uniform, we need only integrate over dxdy. Doing so we get

$$
\int_{1/2}^1 \int_{1/(2y)}^1 dxdy = (1 - ln2)/2
$$

Comment: @wbitting95 Nice work!

Comment: Thank you for your patience and help! I have amended my answer below (keeping the initial error as an educational mistake haha) am the better for it! :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a uniform distribution, we can find this probability by finding the area in the region $0<x,y<1$ such that $xy>1$.

Note that this requires that $x,y\ge 1/2$.
\begin{align*}
\int_{1/2}^1
\int_{\frac{1}{2y}}^1 xydxdy
&=
\int_{1/2}^1
y
\left(
\frac{x^2}{2}
\right)_{\frac{1}{2y}}^{1}
dy
\\
&=
\int_{1/2}^1
y
\left(
\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{8y^2}
\right)dy
\\
&=
\left(\frac{y^2}{4}-\frac{1}{8}\ln(y)\right)_{1/2}^1
\\
&=
\frac{3}{16}-
\frac{\ln(2)}{8}
\end{align*}

I hope this helps and thanks for the awesome question! :D

---

**EDIT**: Fixed a (in hindsight) obvious error!

Because the distribution is uniform, the $xy$ in the integral above is erroneous! The correct answer/implementation of what I was trying to do, which agrees with the Python output of the very patient and helpful @random_0620, is

\begin{align*}
\int_{1/2}^1
\int_{\frac{1}{2y}}^1 dxdy
&=
\int_{1/2}^1
\left(1-\frac{1}{2y}\right)
dy
\\
&=
\left(y - \frac{1}{2}\ln(y)\right)_\frac{1}{2}^1
\\
&=
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\ln(1/2)}{2}
\end{align*}

Thank you all for your patience and constructive feedback and as before, thanks for the awesome question! :D

Comment: 10% seems too low, although it is greater than the absolute lower bound ( (1-sqrt0.5)^2). I guess thanks.

Comment: I will admit that it is certainly lower than I thought it would be when I started on my answer, but as far as I can tell there isn't an error. I guess it's just one of those "Hmm...well how about that!" moments that math is so full of! :D

Comment: I don't believe that this answer is correct, as a simulation in Python puts the probability as ~15.4%, whereas this answer gives ~10%

Comment: Hmm. That's interesting. I will admit I didn't run any Python simulations before working through my answer. I'll see if I can find an error and amend my work where needed.